# Building complex regex pattern using simple patterns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to use regex to extract some texts from textual data. Since some of the regex patterns are getting complex, I wanted to keep things simple for readability of code. Here is an example of what I did.

```
pattern3 = re.compile("[D|d]escription(:)?(\n)+(=*)(\n)+")
pattern4 = re.compile("[D|d]esired [A|a]ction(:)?((\n)+)(=*)| [R|r]equired [A|a]ction(:)?((\n)+)(=*)")

pattern = re.compile(pattern3 | pattern4)
```

But I am getting error. How do I build complex pattern from these small patterns. I am using python's regex module. In fact, I wanted to break up `pattern4` as well. But again, it didn't work.

Comment: The error presumably is `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' and '_sre.SRE_Pattern'`. If you want to improve readability, use `re.VERBOSE` and multiline strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First guess: combine the strings, not the patterns

```
import re 

pattern3_str = "[D|d]escription(:)?(\n)+(=*)(\n)+"
pattern3 = re.compile(pattern3_str)
pattern4_str = "[D|d]esired [A|a]ction(:)?((\n)+)(=*)| [R|r]equired [A|a]ction(:)?((\n)+)(=*)"
pattern4 = re.compile(pattern4_str)

pattern = re.compile(pattern3_str + "|" + pattern4_str)
```